# Query the id and number of times hired for DVDs hired in a month

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a database with several entities that are relevant to this question, such as: MonthlyRental (dvdID, customerID, dateHired, dateReturned).

I have the following query that needs to be translated to an SQL query:

List all DVDs that were hired in October 2015 (including those that were not returned in October). For each DVD, list its unique number and the number of times it was hired. Sort the DVDs in ascending order of DVD numbers.

Would this just be select dvdID where dateHired='October' and count the number of times each DVD appears? (I have made this example simple I know)

Comment: Re "hired in October 2015 (including those that were not returned in October)" The parenthetical remark adds nothing. Is that intentional? Or do you really mean, hired in Oct but not returned in Oct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
select dvdID as 'unique number', count(*) as 'times hired' 
from MonthlyRental 
where month(dateHired) = 8 
group by dvdId
```